# spring XD - http-client add application/json header

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd, spring-el, spring-cloud-dataflow

I've installed Spring XD in my PaaS environment and for legacy issue I'm stuck with version 1.0.0.M1. ( see [reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-cloud-dataflow/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/index.html)).
My goal is to call a http rest API using the `http-client` module. My stream definition is:

`http | httpclient --url='''<my_url>''' --http-method=POST --mappedRequestHeaders=HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS  | log --expression=#root`

Unfortunately, since the `http` module only sends the payload to the `httpclient`, the `httpclient` returns a 415 error due to the absence of the content-type header.

Considering that I can neither add new modules nor modify existing ones (in such a version you can only reference to the spring repository), I would like to use a `tranform` module to inject the content-type header.

How can I achieve such a goal?

Many thanks for your help.

**EDIT**:

I just found that httpclient processor ([link](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-modules/tree/master/httpclient-processor)) supports headersExpression A SpEL expression used to derive the http headers map to use.  However:

```
--headers-expression='{Content-Type:'application/json'}'
```

Gives the following parse exception:

```
    org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:
(pos 1): Property or field 'Content' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage' - maybe not public?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [GH issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-modules/issues/260) for more StackTrace.

First of all it isn't Spring XD any more. Spring Cloud Dataflow is different product and its behavior maybe not that which you had with Spring XD before.

Second: it is in version `1.0.0.RC1` already. So, consider to upgrade.

Now on the problem. Look:

> headersExpression
>
> ```
>  A SpEL expression used to derive the http headers map to use.
> ```

So, this expression must return a `Map` and it is confirmed by the code:

```
if (properties.getHeadersExpression() != null) {
    Map<?, ?> headersMap = properties.getHeadersExpression().getValue(message, Map.class);
```

Now let's take a look into the problem:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 1): Property or field 'Content' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage' - maybe not public?
 org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpMinus.getValueInternal(OpMinus.java:98) ~[spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

`OpMinus` is a root of cause. So, SpEL treats `Content-Type` expression as a `minus` operator.

Sad, of course, but the workaround is like wrapping the `key` into quotes as well:

```
--headers-expression={'Content-Type':'application/json'}
```

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your support! I will double check whether I can upgrade deplying correctly the new version on Bluemix. Regarding the problem here your solution was perfect! Just for the sake of completeness, using the shell to deploy the stream you need to escape the special characters so it becomes: `--headers-expression={\'Content\-type\':\'application\/json\'}`